# How to add a proxy with auth to ChromeDriver on Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, selenium-chromedriver, watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir on Ruby which uses Selenium as its underlying framework. I'm using ChromeDriver, and to set up a proxy I sually did this:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => ["--proxy-server=11.1.1.11:3011"]
```

Sometimes, the proxy comes with user,password authentication like this:

```
11.1.1.11:3011:3011:user:pass
```

but when I try to put that string into `--proxy-server` I get an error.

How can I configure ChromeDriver to use the authentication? I've tried the format often suggested in other SO answers which is:

```
http://user:pass@11.1.1.11:3011
```

but that didn't work. Tried it without the `http` part, also didn't work.

Comment: i have similar issue but none couldn't answer it

Comment: @anemaria were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Any luck with this?